# Suddenly the Android application started to stop resonding

Tags: android, sqlite, android-layout, android-emulator, sqliteopenhelper

I have an insert entry logic into my android application which was responding perfectly till last time I accessed the application.
But it suddenly started to stop responding and running. So please help me whats the error or mistake I have made in my logic or what else would be the problem in my coding which suddenly responded sqlite to behave in such a manner.
Please help me out as soon as possible as I have my final presentation of the android-application today and I am left out with very less time.

Thanks in advance for the help.

REGARDS :)

Following my Create Table Logic:

```
private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1; // db version
    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "db_Blood_Donation"; // db name
    private static final String TABLE_NAME = "Table1"; // table name
    // table fields
    private static final String KEY_ID = "bid";
    private static final String KEY_NAME = "bname";
    private static final String KEY_DATE = "bdate";
    private static final String KEY_GRP = "bgroup";
    private static final String KEY_ADD = "baddress";
    private static final String KEY_PH = "bphno";

    public DBHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        /* ------------- CREATE TABLE ------------- */


        String CREATE_TABLE1 = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NAME + "(" + KEY_ID
                + "INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, " + KEY_NAME + "TEXT, " + KEY_DATE
                + "TEXT, " + KEY_GRP + "TEXT, " + KEY_ADD + "TEXT, " + KEY_PH
                + "TEXT " + ")";

        db.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE1);
        Log.d("Table_Created", "table1");
    }
```

Following is my AddEntry Logic:

```
/* ----------------- ADD USER ------------- */

    void addUser(BDFieldClass user) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
        cv.put(KEY_NAME, user.getBname());
        cv.put(KEY_DATE, user.getBdate());
        cv.put(KEY_GRP, user.getBgroup());
        cv.put(KEY_ADD, user.getBaddress());
        cv.put(KEY_PH, user.getPhno());

        // INSERT ROWS

        db.insertOrThrow(TABLE_NAME, null, cv);
        db.close();
    }
```

Following is the code from which I m calling my Insert Logic:

/*------------------------------- ADD RECORED -------------------------------- */

```
    btnadd.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    EditText ednm = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.txtname);
        String name = ednm.getText().toString();

        eddate = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.txtdate);
        String date1 = eddate.getText().toString();

        EditText edadd = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.txtadd);
        String add = edadd.getText().toString();

        EditText edno = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.txtno);
        String phno = edno.getText().toString();


    dbh.addUser(new BDFieldClass(name,date1,bgrp,add,phno));
```

Following is the LogCat Errors:

```
09-01 06:20:59.087: W/KeyCharacterMap(359): No keyboard for id 0
09-01 06:20:59.097: W/KeyCharacterMap(359): Using default keymap: /system/usr/keychars/qwerty.kcm.bin
09-01 06:21:16.307: D/dalvikvm(359): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed 4630 objects / 232480 bytes in 119ms
09-01 06:21:30.917: D/Table_Created(359): table1
09-01 06:21:30.936: I/Database(359): sqlite returned: error code = 1, msg = table Table1 has no column named bname
09-01 06:21:30.947: D/AndroidRuntime(359): Shutting down VM
09-01 06:21:30.947: W/dalvikvm(359): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001d800)
09-01 06:21:30.976: E/AndroidRuntime(359): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
09-01 06:21:30.976: E/AndroidRuntime(359): android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: table Table1 has no column named bname: , while compiling: INSERT INTO Table1(bname, bphno, bgroup, bdate, baddress) VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?, ?);
09-01 06:21:30.976: E/AndroidRuntime(359):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCompiledSql.native_compile(Native Method)
09-01 06:21:30.976: E/AndroidRuntime(359):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCompiledSql.compile(SQLiteCompiledSql.java:91)
09-01 06:21:30.976: E/AndroidRuntime(359):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCompiledSql.<init>(SQLiteCompiledSql.java:64)
09-01 06:21:30.976: E/AndroidRuntime(359):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.<init>(SQLiteProgram.java:80)
09-01 06:21:30.976: E/AndroidRuntime(359):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.<init>(SQLiteStatement.java:36)
09-01 06:21:30.976: E/AndroidRuntime(359):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.compileStatement(SQLiteDatabase.java:1145)
09-01 06:21:30.976: E/AndroidRuntime(359):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insertWithOnConflict(SQLiteDatabase.java:1536)
09-01 06:21:30.976: E/AndroidRuntime(359):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insertOrThrow(SQLiteDatabase.java:1432)
09-01 06:21:30.976: E/AndroidRuntime(359):  at com.example.blooddonationapp.DBHelper.addUser(DBHelper.java:66)
09-01 06:21:30.976: E/AndroidRuntime(359):  at com.example.blooddonationapp.CreateClass$2.onClick(CreateClass.java:80)
09-01 06:21:30.976: E/AndroidRuntime(359):  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2408)
09-01 06:21:30.976: E/AndroidRuntime(359):  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:8816)
09-01 06:21:30.976: E/AndroidRuntime(359):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
09-01 06:21:30.976: E/AndroidRuntime(359):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
09-01 06:21:30.976: E/AndroidRuntime(359):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
09-01 06:21:30.976: E/AndroidRuntime(359):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
09-01 06:21:30.976: E/AndroidRuntime(359):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
09-01 06:21:30.976: E/AndroidRuntime(359):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
09-01 06:21:30.976: E/AndroidRuntime(359):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
09-01 06:21:30.976: E/AndroidRuntime(359):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
09-01 06:21:30.976: E/AndroidRuntime(359):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
09-01 06:21:33.286: I/Process(359): Sending signal. PID: 359 SIG: 9
```

Comment: You should post the stacktrace. Its more important than the code.

Comment: @wtsang02 I have posted LogCat Status Report please review it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use below string for creating table. Note the addition of spaces at the start of column type

```
   String CREATE_TABLE1 = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NAME + "(" + KEY_ID
            + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, " + KEY_NAME + " TEXT, " + KEY_DATE
            + " TEXT, " + KEY_GRP + " TEXT, " + KEY_ADD + " TEXT, " + KEY_PH
            + " TEXT " + ")";
```

Comment: @Nandeesh.. your Suggestion worked.
and my project came on track.
Thanks again..

Regards :)

Answer (score 1):

The problem goes here: `KEY_NAME + "TEXT, "`. It will crete a column: `bnameTEXT` in your database! You should add one space before `TEXT`.

Comment: Thanks a ton ur suggestion worked and my project again came on track.

REGARDS:)